# How can i achieve a table like this?

Tags: html, css

[image: Table like this]

I tried using boxed elements but it is not coming in a proper way!
Any kind of help is highly appreciated

https://codepen.io/saisree/pen/EXXQGO - link to codepen

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="text-center" colspan="4">Aircraft Status  Display</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> spare</br>STBY</td><td><div class="vr"></div>


    </td>
  </tr>

<tr>
     <td style="width:80px;" ><p style="padding-top:20px;padding-bottom:20px;"  class="boxed4 text-center"
    ><span class="br"></span></p>
   </td>
      <td style="width:80px;" ><p style="padding-top:20px;padding-bottom:20px;"  class="boxed4 text-center"
    ><span class="br"></span></p>
   </td>
      <td style="width:80px;" ><p style="padding-top:20px;padding-bottom:20px;"  class="boxed4 text-center"
    ><span class="br"></span></p>
   </td>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `colspan=n` to make a column the width of n columns:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td></td><td colspan="6">this is wide column</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td><td colspan="6">another wide column</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not completely clear from your image what you are trying to achieve, but if you mean the "half-open" cells, here is an example.

It uses col-spans to merge several cells into one, and different border settings: First a default setting for all cells (for borders on each side), the therse are overwritten by additional CSS rules that have special CSS selectors (with pseudo classes) to only affect certain cells:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  height: 40px;
}
tr:first-of-type > td {
border-bottom: none;
height: 20px;
}
tr:nth-of-type(2) > td {
border-top: none;
height: 40px;
}
tr:nth-of-type(4) > td:not(:first-child) {
border-bottom: none;
}
tr:nth-of-type(5) > td:not(:first-child) {
border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td colspan="4" ;></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td colspan="4" ;></td>
  </tr>  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hey thanks! I was looking for this kind of solution... And is there any way to decrease the border size of first td elements in first tr?

Comment: Well, I edited my snippet once more - you simply can play around with hiding more borders - now the top two rows look like one and have a different size, causing these seemingly cut-off vertical lines.